# Public activity select unique foreign keys by created time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, public-activity

I'm looking to do a query for an activity object in my app. I'm using the `public_activity` gem and I have a list of activities which are connected to several models and I would like to list out the most recent unique activity.

Basically I would like to query the most recent activity for a particular tracking. Let's say that I'm tracking the like button and it's `ID` is `29`. I want to query out the most recent (one) instance of tracking `ID=29` and other tracking IDs. I don't know the querying for rails too well. Right now this is the only line I have which displays all activity:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.id)
```

Let's say I have a table of activities as follows:

```
id  activity_id description created_on
1   3           Like        yesterday
2   3           Unlike      two days ago
3   6           Comment     yesterday
4   7           Review      yesterday
5   7           Review      two days ago
```

I want to pull out the most recent entries of each activity ID into the `@activities` variable like the following:

```
id  activity_id description created_on
1   3           Like        yesterday
3   6           Comment     yesterday
4   7           Review      yesterday
```

Does `public_activity` have a workaround for this?

Comment: if you please elaborate more. Thx

Comment: I've added what I want to pull out, those are just dummy data but my point is made

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `group` and `select` to accomplish this.

```
PublicActivity::Activity.
  select("MAX(created_at) as when, trackable_type").
  group("trackable_type").
  where(owner_id: current_user.id)
```

Here's the output

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| trackable_type          | when                    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Report                  | 2015-11-27 20:25:31 UTC |
| QuickAnswer             | 2016-01-04 23:36:21 UTC |
| Comment                 | 2015-10-23 15:35:32 UTC |
| TakenExam               | 2016-01-04 23:46:11 UTC |
| SeenVideo               | 2015-08-23 21:27:58 UTC |
| Provider                | 2015-09-17 23:47:40 UTC |
| AnswerForRecommendation | 2015-08-18 15:13:03 UTC |
| Subscription            | 2015-08-24 08:37:08 UTC |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```